# How can I generate the data so that there is only one mode?

Tags: r, datatable, max, min, mode

I want to make the mode of a set of data and for this I use the function "max". How can I indicate that if there is more than one value that is the maximum it repeats the operation, and that therefore, this message does not come out: "In sub(object$syntax$docexpr, val, chunk[pos[1L]]) :argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".
I want the dataset to have only one mode.

That is, I want to take the maximum value of a vector, but if there is more than one maximum value, I want to re-generate the data, until I get a data set where there is only one maximum value.

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
## DATA GENERATION


create_table <- function() {
   n_a <- sample(10:25,1)
  n_b <- 50-n_a
  n_c <- sample(10:25,1)
  n_d <- 50-n_c
  A <- rmultinom(1, n_a, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
  F <- rmultinom(1, n_b, prob=c(0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3))
  I <- rmultinom(1, n_c, prob=c(0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1))
  P <- rmultinom(1, n_d, prob=c(0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2))
  matrix(c(A, F, I, P), nrow = 4,
         dimnames = list(c("7", "8", "9", "10"),
           c("3", "4", "5", "6")))
}

public <- create_table()

variant <- sample(1:2, 1)
margins <- list(1, 2, NULL)
prop_public <- round(100*prop.table(public, margins[[variant]]), digits = 2) 

while (length(prop_public) != length(unique(prop_public))) {
  public <- create_table()
  prop_public <- round(100*prop.table(public, margins[[variant]]), digits = 2) 
}

## QUESTION/ANSWER GENERATION

public
prop_public

states = list(c("7", "8", "9", "10"),
           c("3", "4", "5", "6"))

q3 <- switch (variant,
  paste0("¿Cuál es la calificación más frecuente en Física"), 
  paste0("¿Cuál es la calificación más frecuente en la asignatura optativa? " )
)


w1<- public[1,"3"]+public[2,"3"]+public[3,"3"]+public[4,"3"]

w2<- public[1,"4"]+public[2,"4"]+public[3,"4"]+public[4,"4"]

w3<- public[1,"5"]+public[2,"5"]+public[3,"5"]+public[4,"5"]

w4<- public[1,"6"]+public[2,"6"]+public[3,"6"]+public[4,"6"]



v <- max(c(w1, w2, w3, w4))

grupos =  c("3", "4", "5" , "6")
ans <- grupos[c(w1==v, w2==v, w3==v, w4==v)]
c(w1,w2,w3,w4)


v1<-public["7",1]+public["7",2]+public["7",3]+public["7",4]

v2<-public["8",1]+public["8",2]+public["8",3]+public["8",4]

v3<- public["9",1]+public["9",2]+public["9",3]+public["9",4]

v4<- public["10",1]+public["10",2]+public["10",3]+public["10",4]


h1 <- max(c(v1, v2, v3, v4))


grupos1 = c("7", "8", "9", "10")
ans1 <- grupos1[c(v1==h1, v2==h1, v3==h1, v4==h1)]
c(v1,v2,v3,v4)
  
  


sol <- switch (variant, ans, ans1 )
```

[image]

Comment: instead of `ans <- grupos[c(w1==v, w2==v, w3==v, w4==v)]` use `ans <- grupos[ min(which(c(w1==v, w2==v, w3==v, w4==v)))]` . The same with ans1

Comment: Thank you Ric Villalba, but that's not what I'm looking for.

In the example I added, the maximum is 34, then I would have two modes, the 4 and 6. What I want is for that situation not to appear.

Comment: Also, although the error I indicated appeared, the solution was the smaller value. Indeed, with your solution it does not give the error and gives the same solution.

Comment: I want to take the maximum value of a vector, but if there is more than one maximum value, I want to re-generate the data, until I get a data set where there is only one maximum value.

Comment: So you can put all your code inside a `repeat{}` block (except the function definition of course) and replace `sol <- switch (variant, ans, ans1 )` (or the line that produces the error) by: `if (length(ans) == length(ans1) == 4)  {sol <- switch (variant, ans, ans1 ); break}`

Comment: Thank you Ric Villalba,  what you told me works, but instead of 4, it would be 1, since what I want is only to find a maximum value, that is:  " if (length(ans) ==1 & length(ans1) == 1)  {sol <- switch (variant, ans, ans1 ); break}"